# Meta data model for LLVM MI instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

My backend requires some book-keeping for Machine instructions during run-time. In LLVM, I can model it on IR level using meta-data model. However, I could not find any implementation to model debug information at MI level.

Is there any existing model available in LLVM to store debug information for MI?.

Thanks in advance.